# How to get sum of duplicates in array base on two properties and return two arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

```js
var data = 

[
  {
    "amount": 270,
    "xlabel": "25-31/10",
    "datestatus": "past",
    "color": "#E74C3C",
    "y": 270,
    "date": "2020-10-31T00:00:00Z",
    "entityId": 1,
    "entityName": "Lenovo HK",
    "bankName": "BNP Paribas Bank",
    "buyerName": "Microsoft",
    "currency": "USD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 100,
    "xlabel": "25-31/10",
    "datestatus": "past",
    "color": "#E74C3C",
    "y": 100,
    "date": "2020-10-30T00:00:00Z",
    "entityId": 1,
    "entityName": "Lenovo HK",
    "bankName": "BNP Paribas Bank",
    "buyerName": "Microsoft",
    "currency": "USD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 100,
    "xlabel": "01-07/11",
    "datestatus": "future",
    "color": "#2CD9C5",
    "y": 100,
    "date": "2020-11-01T00:00:00Z",
    "entityId": 1,
    "entityName": "Lenovo HK",
    "bankName": "BNP Paribas Bank",
    "buyerName": "Microsoft",
    "currency": "USD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 100,
    "xlabel": "25-31/10",
    "datestatus": "past",
    "color": "#E74C3C",
    "y": 100,
    "date": "2020-10-25T00:00:00Z",
    "entityId": 1,
    "entityName": "Lenovo HK",
    "bankName": "BNP Paribas Bank",
    "buyerName": "Microsoft",
    "currency": "USD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 10,
    "xlabel": "25-31/10",
    "datestatus": "past",
    "color": "#E74C3C",
    "y": 10,
    "date": "2020-10-26T00:00:00Z",
    "entityId": 1,
    "entityName": "Lenovo HK",
    "bankName": "BNP Paribas Bank",
    "buyerName": "Microsoft",
    "currency": "USD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 100,
    "xlabel": "25-31/10",
    "datestatus": "past",
    "color": "#E74C3C",
    "y": 100,
    "date": "2020-10-27T00:00:00Z",
    "entityId": 1,
    "entityName": "Lenovo HK",
    "bankName": "BNP Paribas Bank",
    "buyerName": "Microsoft",
    "currency": "USD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 110,
    "xlabel": "08-14/11",
    "datestatus": "future",
    "color": "#2CD9C5",
    "y": 110,
    "date": "2020-11-09T00:00:00Z",
    "entityId": 1,
    "entityName": "Lenovo SG",
    "bankName": "BNP Paribas Bank",
    "buyerName": "Microsoft",
    "currency": "USD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 90,
    "xlabel": "08-14/11",
    "datestatus": "future",
    "color": "#2CD9C5",
    "y": 90,
    "date": "2020-11-10T00:00:00Z",
    "entityId": 1,
    "entityName": "Lenovo SG",
    "bankName": "BNP Paribas Bank",
    "buyerName": "Microsoft",
    "currency": "USD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 200,
    "xlabel": "08-14/11",
    "datestatus": "future",
    "color": "#2CD9C5",
    "y": 200,
    "date": "2020-11-11T00:00:00Z",
    "entityId": 1,
    "entityName": "Lenovo SG",
    "bankName": "BNP Paribas Bank",
    "buyerName": "Microsoft",
    "currency": "USD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 220,
    "xlabel": "08-14/11",
    "datestatus": "future",
    "color": "#2CD9C5",
    "y": 220,
    "date": "2020-11-14T00:00:00Z",
    "entityId": 1,
    "entityName": "Lenovo SG",
    "bankName": "BNP Paribas Bank",
    "buyerName": "Microsoft",
    "currency": "USD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 100,
    "xlabel": "15-21/11",
    "datestatus": "future",
    "color": "#2CD9C5",
    "y": 100,
    "date": "2020-11-21T00:00:00Z",
    "entityId": 1,
    "entityName": "Lenovo SG",
    "bankName": "BNP Paribas Bank",
    "buyerName": "Microsoft",
    "currency": "USD"
  }
]



function getFormationgData(data) {
    var sum = [];
    let counts = data.reduce((prev, curr) => {
      let amount = prev.get(curr.xlabel) || 0;
      prev.set(curr.xlabel, curr.amount + amount, curr.entityId, curr.entityName);
      return prev;
    }, new Map());

    // then, map your counts object back to an array
    let reducedObjArr = [...counts].map(([xlabel, amount, entityId,
      entityName]) => ({
       xlabel, amount,
        entityId,
        entityName
      }))
    //let reducedObjArr = [...counts].map(data => data)
    return reducedObjArr;
  }
  
  
 
 var pastData = getFormationgData(data.filter(w=>w.datestatus == 'past'));
    var futureData = getFormationgData(data.filter(w=>w.datestatus == 'future'));

    console.log(pastData, 'pastData', pastData.length)
    console.log(futureData, 'futureData', futureData.length)
```

I am trying to do sum of duplicates of amount in array base on two other properties and retrive past, future two arrays

I am getting data as

Assume today is 3-11-2020

```
 [
{
    "amount": 270,
    "xlabel": "01-07/11", (weekfirst, lastdate and month)
    "datestatus": "past",// past, future
    "color": "#E74C3C",
    "y": 270,
    "date": "2020-02-11T00:00:00Z",
    "entityId": 1,
    "entityName": "Lenovo HK",
    "bankName": "BNP Paribas Bank",
    "buyerName": "Microsoft",
    "currency": "USD"
  },

{
    "amount": 270,
    "xlabel": "01-07/11", (weekfirst, lastdate and month)
    "datestatus": "future",// past, future
    "color": "#E74C3C",
    "y": 270,
    "date": "2020-03-11T00:00:00Z",
    "entityId": 1,
    "entityName": "Lenovo HK",
    "bankName": "BNP Paribas Bank",
    "buyerName": "Microsoft",
    "currency": "USD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 270,
    "xlabel": "01-07/11", (weekfirst, lastdate and month)
    "datestatus": "future",// past, future
    "color": "#E74C3C",
    "y": 270,
    "date": "2020-04-11T00:00:00Z",
    "entityId": 1,
    "entityName": "Lenovo HK",
    "bankName": "BNP Paribas Bank",
    "buyerName": "Microsoft",
    "currency": "USD"
  }.....]
```

I am trying to achive based on xlabel, datastatus, entity

I am  able to format it based on xlabel, not getting idea how to get two seperate arrays based on status as well

as per current logic it retuing 4 items(total lenght 11)

Please find attached fiddle the way I tried,,

I am expecting function should return twotypes of arrays with all other data properties

my expectation is the current week dates only come under past and future array

pastarray = [] futurearray = []

By Below answer I achied 80%  please find snippet,, but it not returning all properties in obj

Can any one help me on this

Comment: Instead of a Fiddle, can you post the problem using the "<>" button? It allows you to include all the elements you need, and is more likely to elicit a response. Also please remember to include the exact output you expect to achieve. I find it difficult to understand your description of what you want to achieve, but I bet it would be much easier to understand with a concrete example. Another thing you can do to encourage respondents is to get rid of as many data fields as possible, while still retaining the problem.

Comment: ^ See: [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood the task correctly.

**I. Sum of duplicates**

What does the algorithm do:

1. Sorts the values from `amount` into two separate ARRAYs for past and future.
2. Removes the unique values from ARRAYs
3. Calculates the total value of the remaining values in the array.

```js
var data = [
  {
    "amount": 270,
    "xlabel": "25-31/10",
    "datestatus": "past",
    "color": "#E74C3C",
    "y": 270,
    "date": "2020-10-31T00:00:00Z",
    "entityId": 1,
    "entityName": "Lenovo HK",
    "bankName": "BNP Paribas Bank",
    "buyerName": "Microsoft",
    "currency": "USD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 100,
    "xlabel": "25-31/10",
    "datestatus": "past",
    "color": "#E74C3C",
    "y": 100,
    "date": "2020-10-30T00:00:00Z",
    "entityId": 1,
    "entityName": "Lenovo HK",
    "bankName": "BNP Paribas Bank",
    "buyerName": "Microsoft",
    "currency": "USD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 100,
    "xlabel": "01-07/11",
    "datestatus": "future",
    "color": "#2CD9C5",
    "y": 100,
    "date": "2020-11-01T00:00:00Z",
    "entityId": 1,
    "entityName": "Lenovo HK",
    "bankName": "BNP Paribas Bank",
    "buyerName": "Microsoft",
    "currency": "USD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 100,
    "xlabel": "25-31/10",
    "datestatus": "past",
    "color": "#E74C3C",
    "y": 100,
    "date": "2020-10-25T00:00:00Z",
    "entityId": 1,
    "entityName": "Lenovo HK",
    "bankName": "BNP Paribas Bank",
    "buyerName": "Microsoft",
    "currency": "USD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 10,
    "xlabel": "25-31/10",
    "datestatus": "past",
    "color": "#E74C3C",
    "y": 10,
    "date": "2020-10-26T00:00:00Z",
    "entityId": 1,
    "entityName": "Lenovo HK",
    "bankName": "BNP Paribas Bank",
    "buyerName": "Microsoft",
    "currency": "USD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 100,
    "xlabel": "25-31/10",
    "datestatus": "past",
    "color": "#E74C3C",
    "y": 100,
    "date": "2020-10-27T00:00:00Z",
    "entityId": 1,
    "entityName": "Lenovo HK",
    "bankName": "BNP Paribas Bank",
    "buyerName": "Microsoft",
    "currency": "USD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 110,
    "xlabel": "08-14/11",
    "datestatus": "future",
    "color": "#2CD9C5",
    "y": 110,
    "date": "2020-11-09T00:00:00Z",
    "entityId": 1,
    "entityName": "Lenovo SG",
    "bankName": "BNP Paribas Bank",
    "buyerName": "Microsoft",
    "currency": "USD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 90,
    "xlabel": "08-14/11",
    "datestatus": "future",
    "color": "#2CD9C5",
    "y": 90,
    "date": "2020-11-10T00:00:00Z",
    "entityId": 1,
    "entityName": "Lenovo SG",
    "bankName": "BNP Paribas Bank",
    "buyerName": "Microsoft",
    "currency": "USD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 200,
    "xlabel": "08-14/11",
    "datestatus": "future",
    "color": "#2CD9C5",
    "y": 200,
    "date": "2020-11-11T00:00:00Z",
    "entityId": 1,
    "entityName": "Lenovo SG",
    "bankName": "BNP Paribas Bank",
    "buyerName": "Microsoft",
    "currency": "USD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 220,
    "xlabel": "08-14/11",
    "datestatus": "future",
    "color": "#2CD9C5",
    "y": 220,
    "date": "2020-11-14T00:00:00Z",
    "entityId": 1,
    "entityName": "Lenovo SG",
    "bankName": "BNP Paribas Bank",
    "buyerName": "Microsoft",
    "currency": "USD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 100,
    "xlabel": "15-21/11",
    "datestatus": "future",
    "color": "#2CD9C5",
    "y": 100,
    "date": "2020-11-21T00:00:00Z",
    "entityId": 1,
    "entityName": "Lenovo SG",
    "bankName": "BNP Paribas Bank",
    "buyerName": "Microsoft",
    "currency": "USD"
  }
];

//////////////////////////////////////////////

function dataCalc(data, z) {

    var fu = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (data[i].datestatus === z) {
        fu.push(data[i].amount);
      }
    }

    function noUnique(array) {
      var map = new Map();
      array.forEach(a => map.set(a, (map.get(a) || 0) + 1));
      return array.filter(a => map.get(a) > 1);
    }

    var fucls = noUnique(fu);
    
    var res = fucls.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
    
    return res;

}


console.log(dataCalc(data, 'past'));
console.log(dataCalc(data, 'future'));
```

---

**II. Future and Past - seperate arrays**

This function returns an `array` with only a `future` or `past` values from `data`

```
function dataSort(data, z) {

    var fu = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (data[i].datestatus === z) {
        fu.push(data[i]);
      }
    }

    return fu;

}

console.log(dataSort(data, 'past'));
console.log(dataSort(data, 'future'));
```

Comment: Thanks, with this solution I got idea modified my code ,,, I modified my question